# Flask-Restless support for datastores other than models or tables

Tags: flask-restless

Flask-Restless support and creates API's over models . can it also support custom collections?Lets say i design a datastructure or a object which i provide getter and setters can it be used as a model in Flask-restless.

Comment: should you look at flask-restful instead? http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html